# php pdf file download : Failed to load PDF Document

Tags: php, pdf, download

I am trying to download a pdf file using php . I can download text file and image and 
    My **`PHP`** Code :

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));    
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");   // pdf might change to another format eg. doc,docx
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
echo fread($fp, 65536);
flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp);
```

and here is the **`HTML`**

part :

```
<a href="download.php?file=abc">Download CV</a>
```

In my case I am able to download the PDF file and it's showing the memory size also but when I opened it show me error like :

> Failed to load PDF Document

I am not getting any error and I tried to change the memory limits and all but not working . Any help will be really appreciated .

> EDIT :

I need to download all the file format with some simple changes in my code .
   example :

```
 header("Content-Type: application/pdf");   // pdf might change to another format eg. doc,docx
```

I don't want to save the PDF file which is displayed in the browser because in the case of other formats I cannot directly save from browser  .

> When I tried to open file from the downloads folder it shows an error
>   like :

**Adobe reader could not open the file name abc.pdf because it's either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged**

Comment: if I may ask, why do you need this header header("Content-Type: application/download");

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome has "Failed to load PDF document" error message on inline PDFs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670785/chrome-has-failed-to-load-pdf-document-error-message-on-inline-pdfs)

Comment: @Saty no it does not solve my problem exactly . It show the contents on the browser even though I can save because it's PDF file . But not with any other formats

Comment: try solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101160/how-to-make-mpdf-6-1-work-with-php-7-1-5

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Change your

```
echo fread($fp, 65536);
```

to

```
echo fread($fp, filesize($file));
```

My guess is the length of the pdf file is different on what you specified.