# Opening pdf with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm storing pdf's on the filesystem and path in database table. I want now based on the ID to open corresponded PDF document in the browser. How can I open and read PDF's?
What I have so far is this

```
require_once("database.php");

if(isset($_GET['upload_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['upload_id']))
{
    $fileFolder='uploads/';

    $sql = "SELECT file FROM documents WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $_GET['upload_id']);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

    $file = $resArray['file'];

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileFolder.$file));
    @read($fileFolder.$file);

}
```

When I click on the button and tried to open the pdf I got this message in the Chrome

> Failed to load PDF document
>   RELOAD

Comment: `$file` is undefined in your code!!

Comment: It was my mistake while I copy/paste the source. I have edited my question.

Comment: make sure that the path stored on $file is right, and try an absolute path for $fileFolder

Comment: echo `$fileFolder.$file` and check your path

Comment: I don't get file name .. when I `echo $fileFolder.$file` I've got only the folder: `uploads/`

Comment: `print_r( $resArray);` and check what it return

Comment: to prevent the execution of file loading if the pdf doesn´t exists you should add somesthing like `if(file_exists($file)){/*do stuff*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your file name using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` which Return next row as an array indexed by `column name`

```
$sql = "SELECT file FROM documents WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(":id", $_GET['upload_id']);
$result->execute();     
$resArray = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$file = $resArray['file'];// get your file name
```

By using `fetchAll`

Pass `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0`

```
 $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
 $file = $resArray[0];// get your file name
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Now I get the correct path and document but still got this message. `Failed to load PDF document`

Comment: On the `echo $fileFolder.$file` I got `uploads/c970464e4da7eef4bb63c4c510b2ef36.pdf` which is correct

Comment: Flollow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670785/chrome-has-failed-to-load-pdf-document-error-message-on-inline-pdfs

Comment: Yes, this was helpful. Now PDF is loaded properly. Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
require_once("database.php");

if(isset($_GET['upload_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['upload_id']))
{
    $fileFolder='uploads/';

    $sql = "SELECT file FROM documents WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $_GET['upload_id']);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

    $file = $resArray['file'];

    $myFilePath = $fileFolder . $file;

    if (file_exists($myFilePath)) {

        // the file exists, so open it
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileFolder.$file));
        @read($fileFolder.$file);

    } else {

        // the file doesn´t exits
        // handle the error if neccessary
        echo "the file doesn´t exist";

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but still failed to load and the problem was in headers. With @Saty's comment to the other question I fixed it.